# How do you handle platform events that create objects with dependencies among them?

Tags: platform-event

We're in the process of migrating our CRM to salesforce via platform events. We have platform events that create PersonAccounts and then immediately other objects that have a dependency on the PersonAccount. It seems that event ordering is guaranteed for a platform event but not between multiple types of platform events. So even if we publish in order I believe an Opportunity with reference to a non-existent PersonAccount could be created.

### Potential solutions

One idea we've had is to make a single platform event but that is hard to manage, and another is to create a dummy person account however that apparently messes with other business processes.

Is there any other potential solutions? Is there a way to guarantee ordering with different platform events?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Multiple types of PE with separate subscribing triggers or flows will, as you say, receive events out of logical conceptual order. Solutions to this will be opinion-based and complex - but IMHO, you'll need to capture the incoming events into "holding tank" objects that track when all requisite components to properly construct the database have been received and then process. You're basically trying to reconstruct a graph from elements but parents need to get inserted before children

Comment: WARNING: platform events are not guaranteed to be delivered. It is a bad idea to entrust them with important data.